# Newsletter functionality for a MERN-Stack eCommerce Website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

(first time posting here, don't throw rocks at me just yet )
I'd need some guidance regarding a MERN Stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node) eCommerce Project I'm trying to implement.
I created an e-commerce website, using MERN and I'd like to add a newsletter functionality but I'm not sure what's the best way to do it 
This is a link to the github project : https://github.com/Beny9313/shopIT-eCommerce.git
Link to the deployed website :
https://shopit-ecommerce-beny.herokuapp.com/
My problem is as follows: I'd like to send out a link to users, every time a new product is added to the website.
I implemented the consent part (users can opt-in or opt-out of getting an email notification, the choice being saved in the DB; I'll have a question regarding this later on)
What I need to find out how to do is :

1. How do I send the email (should I try to get "allUsers" method from my "authController.js" code as a basis, filter users by consent, send a mail with nodemailer - already have mail with nodemailer for password reset)
2. I need some way to pass on the newly created product's ID ( I cannot think of a way of passing on this parameter to my other method, in which I try to send an email to all consented users with a link directly to my new password )
   Regarding my issue with the UI: I'd like to have the checkbox reflect the exact value in my consent variable, for each user. For now, the checkbox remains unchecked on every edit, regardless of the consent variable.
   Most likely this is due to the fact that I initialize my useState with "False". Tried without initialization, the logic goes off. Is there a fix to this, should I use a different hook, if so, which would be more suitable for my needs?
   I'm here to provide further details if something is not clear

Comment: I would suggest that you make another collection with the subscriber id || id&email in it and send an email to the whole collection in patches if the user base is big

Comment: can you clarify the second point

Comment: If you mean point 2 from my main issue: I want the mail to be sent every time a new product is being created. That's why I would've needed the productID, to pass it on to my email sending part, so that the user can directly access the new product

If you mean the issue with the UI : the checkbox for consent is unchecked every time I try to edit consent, from all parts. It doesn't matter if the consent is true or false, the checkbox will be unchecked for starters.